Why do all my 16-bit microphones appear as 32-bit float audio streams?
Why does Windows only give me 32-bit float audio streams even though both my microphones only produce 16-bit audio?
I've tried in WinRT/C# (AudioEncodingProperties) and also Media Foundation/C++ (IMFMediaSource). Same results either way... 32-bit float is the only profile available.
Is there a way to just detect the true sample rate of a microphone and get the unmodified sound data?
Btw, I need to capture video as well, so I need to work within APIs that allow me to capture both simultaneously and keep them sync'd.

You typically consume audio in a way that allows you to share mic with other applications. Exclusive mode streams should let you negotiate format in a more direct way.

@RomanRyltsov Although the docs don't seem to mention anything about the mode having an impact on the available formats (only latency and other UX stuff), I did experiment just in case. Also tried switching AudioProcessing to Raw. Unfortunately nothing changes.
var settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings
{
AudioDeviceId = microphone.Id,
AudioProcessing = Windows.Media.AudioProcessing.Raw,
VideoDeviceId = camera.Id,
SharingMode = MediaCaptureSharingMode.ExclusiveControl
};

Out of curiosity, what's wrong with 32-bit float? also you mixed all APIs together so it's hard to tell for everything. The one you mentioned in the last comment above is the worst option for getting original untouched content, and I would still assume that Media Foundation (and surely WASAPI) should give you the 16-bit option.
